# Java HashMap content to String

Tags: java, hashmap

**Please read comments before You downmark!**

I want convert content of `HashMap` to `String` as converting `ArrayList` to `String` using `Arrays.toString(arrayList)`.

**Is it possible ? 
There is easy way to do this?**

Do I must have to iteration and appending it using `Iterator` ? As example:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyObject>> objectMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<>>();

//.... put many items to objectMap

Iterator it = objectMap.entrySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
  Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
  System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
}
```

I think that it is different because of pair `<String, ArrayList>` not `<String, Integer>`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `toString()` of the `Map`:

```
String content = objectMap.toString();
```

`Map` overrides the `toString()` method, so you can easily get the contents of map.

**I should give an example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, List<MyObject>> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyObject(12, 12));
    objectMap.put("aaaa", list);
    String content = objectMap.toString();
    System.out.println("content = " + content);
}

private static class MyObject {
    int min;
    int max;

    public MyObject(int max, int min) {
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject{" +
                "max=" + max +
                ", min=" + min +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And it is the output:

```
content = {aaaa=[MyObject{max=12, min=12}]}
```

***So it means it works well***

Comment: Nope, it don't work.

Comment: What is the reason of don't work?

Comment: It return bad `String`, not content but strange `String` about package where it from.

Comment: This is the reason: `public final String toString() { return key + "=" + value; }`. If value is an object, its `toString()` is not called

Comment: Reimplement toString() method in HashMap. Be aware of checking what is the object type - if it's not a collection - then invoke toString on object, otherwise iterate again over the collection and therefore invoke toString() on consecutive objects.

Comment: I think that the problem is different, I don't have pairs `<Key, Integer>` but `<Key, ArrayList>`

Comment: @Czarq92 did you override the `toString()` method in your `MyObject` class?

Comment: Yes, but it return name of package, not content of `HashMap`

Comment: @Czarq92 I updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: I know this what You are telling but I have no idea why it returns not content of `HashMap` but my name of package :/

Comment: Look. My `HashMap` contain [This](http://postimg.org/image/hl2x36fl3), but when I try `.toString()` it returns [This](http://postimg.org/image/dqofjrjq7)

Comment: Could you show me MyObject class how did you implemented the toString?

Comment: Sure, [image](http://postimg.org/image/6s1w7gd0n/). I use calling `MyObject` only for shorter question.

Comment: It is OK, and toString method is overrides correctly, I have tested here, it all works well. Maybe it is some other problem.

Comment: Yea I search this OTHER PROBLEM but I have no idea... `MyObject` implements `Serializable` it can made problem ?

Comment: No, this problem is not belongs to Serializable

Comment: It works great. Thank you.

Comment: returns hash instead...

Comment: @vintproykt When you learn well Java, then you will know this. Now hard work to learn first! Good Luck!!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil thanks, that's my bottleneck with legacy codebase.